# Getting access to branches in linked repositories on Github

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository pedz/ruby which is a fork from shyouhei/ruby which is a fork from ruby/ruby.

ruby/ruby has a branch called 1_9_3 that shyouhei/ruby does not have.

Is there a way for me to get access to the 1_9_3 branch of ruby/ruby?

Note that I can not fork ruby/ruby -- at least I don't know how.  The normal "fork" button has been replied with a "your fork" button when I'm on the ruby/ruby page.  Hitting that button puts me on my pedz/ruby page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get access the 1_9_3 branch on your local repository, then:

```
git remote add upstream url://to/ruby/repo
git fetch upstream
git checkout upstream/1_9_3
```

That will give you access to the branch locally.  If you want that branch to be on shyouhei, then continue with:

```
git push origin 1_9_3
```

Comment: I'll try this in a short while.  Question: is "upstream" a special name or can it be arbitrary?

Comment: For the 3rd step I did as you suggested and got put on a detached HEAD.  So, I tried: git checkout ruby_1_9_3 and that worked.

Comment: I intentionally put you on a detached head so that the upstream of ruby_1_9_3 could be your local report by default. Perhaps what you wanted, perhaps not.

Comment: @pedz upstream can be arbitrarily named